# How to add a condition inside or after .Select() using Linq EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

My issue is simple but I cannot solve this and I have searched over the internet but one of them matches my issue.
This is my code:

```
    public Producto VerificarExTalla(int id, bool related = true)
    {
        var productos = _context.Productos.AsQueryable();

        if (related)
        {
            productos = productos
                .Include(s => s.Categoria)
                .Include(s => s.DetalleTallas)
                .Include(s => s.DetalleTallas.Select(a => a.Talla));
        }

        return productos
            .Where(s => s.Id == id)
            .SingleOrDefault();

    }
```

I am trying to perform a condition after `.Select()` . This is what I have tried but did not work:

```
.Include(s => s.DetalleTallas.Select(a => a.Talla).Where(a => a.EstadoTallaa == false));
```

And also tried this, inside .Select:

```
.Include(s => s.DetalleTallas.Select(a => a.Talla.EstadoTallaa == false));
```

both gives me the same error:

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
> Parameter name: path'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code it appears that you want to achieve following -

1. Get Productos including related Categoria and DetalleTallas
2. DetalleTallas list will be filter to include records with EstadoTallaa == false
3. Get the Productos only with id matched with the parameter value

As a simple logical programmer I would like to write as follows -

```
productos = productos.Where(p=> p.Id == id)
                     .Include(s => s.Categoria)
                     .Include(s => s.DetalleTallas.Where(d=> d.EstadoTallaa == false));
```

But sadly it would not work! It will display error "Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid".

So this can be rewritten as like this -

```
productos = productos.Where(p=> p.Id == id)
                     .Select(p => new Productos
                     {
                        Id = p.Id,
                        Categoria = p.Categoria
                        // some other properties of Productos
                        DetalleTallas = p.DetalleTallas.Where(d => d.EstadoTallaa == false).ToList()
                      });
```

Answer (score 0):

The error shown inline says that the navigation feature of EF has thrown an exception. To be more precise `.Include()` is not working as expected

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property
> defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation
> properties and the Select operator for collection navigation
> properties. Parameter name: path'

The reason being `.AsQueryable()`was called on `Productos` DbSet which no longer makes it a linq to entities query and rather becomes a normal list query. For `.Include()` to work, ensure `.Include()` is called directly on the DbSet itself.

```
public Producto VerificarExTalla(int id, bool related = true)
{
    if (related)
    {
        productos = _context.Productos
            .Include(s => s.Categoria)
            .Include(s => s.DetalleTallas)
            .Include(s => s.DetalleTallas.Select(a => a.Talla));
    }

    return _context.Productos
        .Where(s => s.Id == id)
        .SingleOrDefault();

}
```